# Apache Kafka - kafka-server-start.sh is not getting started

Tags: apache-kafka

I am currently studying kafka and new , I am trying to start the `kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` but getting the below error message, I searched stackoverflow and i am unable to get the solution. Could anyone please advise how to fix this.

Error Message:

```
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default 
configuration: logging only errors to the console.
21:48:52.090 [main] FATAL kafka.Kafka$ - null
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.parseCsvList(CoreUtils.scala:213) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:742) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:691) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58) [kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:?]
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Java 1.8 build 101, zookeeper version 3.4 and kafka version 2.11-0.9

Zookeeper properties (zoo.cfg):

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.10/data
clientPort=2181
```

kafka properties (server.properties):

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/usr/local/kafka/kafka-log-1
num.partitions=2
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Comment: do you have java or scala in your system?

Comment: Have you tried it with a more recent version of Kafka? Currently it's 2.0, and you're using 0.9

Comment: Looking at the kafka properties `listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{HOSTNAME}}:9092` or `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

Comment: @Deadpool, Yes I have java and i have mentioned the version in my question and scala I have 2.12 version.

Comment: @Robin Moffatt, Yes I have tried latest version of kafka scala version 2.11, i didnt try 2.12, will give a try and update over this.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan, Let me add the listeners host i any of the tutorial listerners wasnt mentioned, let me try that as well.

Meanwhile if any of you able to figure out what could be the issue , Please do let me know the fix which you have implemented.

Comment: @KarthikRamachandran I'm talking about the version of Kafka, not Scala. From https://kafka.apache.org/downloads you can get  kafka_2.11-2.0.0 which is Apache Kafka 2.0

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, I tried with latest version kafka_2.11-2.0.0 it is still not working in my environment I am not sure what is missing. Getting the same error `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found`.

Comment: You should be able to ignore logger errors. However, you should definitely [edit] your question to include the errors from the newest version of Kafka, plus you should really upgrade your Java 8 version

Comment: Also, FWIW, Ubuntu 14.04 is also fairly old (16.04 generally more widely supported)... see if you can follow this, though https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cos-quickstart.html#cos-quickstart or this https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install

Comment: @cricket_007, Even the newest version of kafka getting the same error, any way will edit my question for better clarity, I have the java 8 build 101 you want me to upgrade to 162 or even newer build of java 8 ?

Comment: @cricket_007, ubuntu14.04 is pretty older will upgrade , sure will follow the link which you have provided from confluent.

Comment: For a brand new cluster, the most recent supported Java version, the better. Currently, that's 1.8u192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally a sign of a Scala version issue; the software being ran is trying to find a Scala internal method that is not available in the version you have installed

```
NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$
```

According to your comment

> scala I have 2.12 version.

I don't think Scala 2.12 existed when Kafka 0.9 was even released, but if you don't plan on downgrading Scala, then you must use a Kafka version built with 2.12.

On the Apache Kafka site, you can find `Scala 2.12  - kafka_2.12-2.0.0.tgz` links.

Or you can use `apt-get` to install Kafka via [Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install), then you can use something like `sudo service start confluent-kafka`

Comment: Sure will try to install kafka2.12-2.0.0 for scala 2.12 either tar ball or through `apt-get install` , I thought it should be like `spark` where it should be having its version of scala. One more thing i am not sure how `kafka` is working fine in  cloudera quickstart vm 5.8 (running from parcel directory without activating it) where it has java 7 build 67, and it doesnt hava scala, it has spark 1.6 scala 2.11.8. Any way will try your solution and update here.

Comment: You do not need Scala pre-installed, but if you do, then it's libraries being available to the `JAVA_HOME` will cause issues. Besides that, the Scala 2.11 versions of Kafka are more tested (by Confluent, the enterprise support company and main developers for Kafka)

Comment: Scala version 2.12 kafka is working as per the link which you have shared. Also there was kafka docker which available through github landoop/fast-data-dev which is working for 2.11 kafka version 1.1.1. Thanks for your solution on my learnings.

Comment: the `confluentinc` images are generally more up to date than the landoop ones